Ruby Unicorn Server Memory Usage
I've been fiddling about with Rails 5.2, Ruby 2.7.8 and Unicorn 4.8.3, trying to understand the memory pattern usage, and I'd appreciate any kind of pointers in this direction, as I seem to find close-to-no documentation.
From my observations, what happens when the rails application boots with unicorn is that the whole app is eager loaded (assuming we're in a prod environment), thus creating a lot of railties objects in the application which then run the files defining class objects etc.
However, my question is what happens once the master is done and it starts forking:
From what I saw, there is an inverse linear relationship between the master and its workers. So what happens is, after a few requests, the workers' memory increases, while the master's memory decreases.
Given that workers are individual processes, and starting from Ruby 2.0 they behave according to COW policy, I would have kind of expected them to increase, while the master's memory would stay the same. So, master big, workers slim.
Perhaps once the master gets touched by the GC everything else gets copied to the workers? I'm not entirely sure even if my assumptions are correct, as memory in ruby is still a bit of a mystery to me.
So, my question here is, why does the master memory decrease while the worker's one increases with virtually the same amount?
Apologies for the verbose message, and thank you for any attempts at clarifying this.
